# Could a foreign key be defined, whose fields belong to different but related tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Given four tables:

```
CREATE TABLE LIST_A (
    A INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (A)
)

CREATE TABLE LIST_B (
    A INT,
    B INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (A, B),
    FOREIGN KEY (A) REFERENCES LIST_A (A)
)

CREATE TABLE LIST_C (
    C INT,
    A INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (C),
    FOREIGN KEY (A) REFERENCES LIST_A (A)
)

CREATE TABLE LIST_D (
    C INT,
    D INT,
    B INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (C, D),
    FOREIGN KEY (C) REFERENCES LIST_C (C)
)
```

I want to add another constraint: Given a row in `LIST_D`, whose primary is `(C0,D0)`, and its parent row in `LIST_C`, whose primary key is `C0`, the pair `(LIST_C.A, LIST_D.B)` must reference `LIST_B (A, B)`. How do I implement this in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: You can't have a foreign key made up from columns from two different tables. A foreign key is always a link between one table and another - not between two (or more) tables on one end, and another on the other end

Comment: @marc_s: I do not know how to express this in simple terms, so I will just hope I can make my point clear. Think of `LIST_A` and `LIST_C` as "header" tables, and of `LIST_B` and `LIST_D` as their respective "details." I want that each `C` header be associated to an `A` header; and I also want that each `D` detail associated to a particular `C`header be associated to a `B` detail associated to the same `A` header the `C` header is associated to.

Comment: No matter how you say it: you cannot have a foreign key made up of two columns from two different tables ...

Comment: @marc_s: Is there an alternative way to express the idea I am trying to model? I know I could make it work in the following inelegant way: Let `A` be a part of `LIST_C`'s primary key. Then, in order to preserve the relationship between `LIST_C` and `LIST_D`, add `A` as a field of `LIST_D`. Finally, to preserve the uniqueness of `C` in `LIST_C`, add an `UNIQUE` constraint on that field. // But this is clearly a design hack, and, given the scope of my project, I must keep it clean at least at the design level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is important (both for us and for you) to know the the purpose for adding the additional foreign key?

Depending on the exact problem you are trying to solve (data validation on entry, cascading deletes, etc) and the flexibility that you have for solving them (ability or inability to alter the data structure), you could implement logical constraints through triggers. We use this approach at times when we just need to catch edge conditions that should rarely, if ever, occur.

If triggers are insufficient for your situation and foreign keys are required, then about the only option that you have left (without redesigning all of the tables) is to store LIST_C.A into LIST_D and then create the FKey back to LIST_B.

The other option is to redesign it such that you have intermediate tables that contain the appropriate links between all of the tables, but it doesn't sound like this is desirable.